# visualforce action support rerender not working

Tags: rerender, inputfield, outputpanel

I am trying to display a field when the value in select option changes. The code is not executed when any change happen, because i am checking the value with status.

My code :

```
                  <tr>
                    <td class="leftColumn">
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Conference Call" for="conferenceList" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:actionRegion renderRegionOnly="false">
                            <apex:inputField id="conferenceList" required="true" value="{!goToMeetingEvent.Conference_Call__c}">
                                <!--<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="PrivateNumb" action="{!checkConferenceValue}" status="selected...." />-->
                                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="PrivateNumb" status="status..."/>
                            </apex:inputField>                                
                        </apex:actionRegion>

                            <apex:outputPanel id="PrivateNumb" rendered="{!if(goToMeetingEvent.Conference_Call__c == 'Private', True, false)}">
                                <apex:outputLabel>Private Number </apex:outputLabel>
                                <apex:inputText value="{!privateNumber}" required="true"/>
                            </apex:outputPanel>

                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Does any one have any idea why this issue is coming up. Please to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use one wrapper panel for `re-rendering`and one for the `render` procedure. Imagine your panel `id="PrivateNumb"` was not rendered because of the `rendered="XXX"` condition on the page load. Then you can not access this panel from other components (with `reRender="PrivateNumb"`) because the `PrivateNumb` is just not existing on the page.

Try to use the following construct:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="PrivateNumb" layout="none">
    <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!if(goToMeetingEvent.Conference_Call__c == 'Private', True, false)}">
        <apex:outputLabel>Private Number </apex:outputLabel>
        <apex:inputText value="{!privateNumber}" required="true"/>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Yes, I have made the changes as per you mentioned. But still I am not able to get it working. The filed is not getting display. Not even the status us is getting display.